# Change image permission in c#

Tags: c#, image, permissions

I have a picturebox which I loaded an image. I dont want to change the dimensions of the picturebox. I want to be able to change images width and height but for that I need to change its permissions from readonly to read-write. How can i do that programmatically? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
```

-

```
 private void SetFullAccessAttribute(string fileName)
        {
            string path = fileName;
            DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
            System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier everyone = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
            sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
            Directory.SetAccessControl(path, sec);
        }
```

P.S. in order to successfully execute the code above, you should be running your application in elevated permissions